# rewrite rule on plugin activation

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules

I Have Developed a plugin. And I created a rewrite rule manually in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?id=$1
```

This rule is used to get the data after the index.php as id. It's working correctly. But I want to create this rewrite rule on my plugin activation. I searched a lot, But little confused. In my rule, http://www.url.com/index.php/example if this is the url I need to get example as id in $_GET.

How can i solve this situation?.

Comment: are you sure this rewrite rule doesn't interfere with other rewrite rules of WordPress ?

Comment: This is rewrite rule is working correctly, doesn't interfere with any of the wordpress pages or posts. I just want to create rewrite rule for custom url.

Comment: the url look like this. www.myblog.com/john so i need to get the john.

Answer (score 0):

finally I completed, using this below hook

> mod_rewrite_rules

```
function output_htaccess( $rules ) {
$new_rules = <<<EOD
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./index.php?id=$1


EOD;
return  $new_rules . $rules;
}
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'output_htaccess');
```